# defined variables and methods in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

on top of jquery file i have all method and properties defined . i want to make changes in file so for study purpose i need to know what is this called?

```
  function ImageFlow ()
{   

    /* Setting option defaults */
    this.defaults =
    {
        animationSpeed:     50,             /* Animation speed in ms */
        aspectRatio:        1.964,          /* Aspect ratio of the ImageFlow container (width divided by height) */

        imageFocusMax:      3,              /* Max number of images on each side of the focussed one */
        imagePath:          '',             /* Path to the images relative to the reflect_.php script */
        imageScaling:       true,           /* Toggle image scaling */ 
        imagesHeight:       0.67,           /* Height of the images div container in percent */
        imagesM:            1.0,            /* Multiplicator for all images in percent */
        onClick:            function() { /*document.location = this.url;*/ flipIt(this) },   /* Onclick behaviour */
        opacity:            true,          /* Toggle image opacity */
        opacityArray:       [10,8,6,4],   /* Image opacity (range: 0 to 10) first value is for the focussed image */
        percentLandscape:   118,            /* Scale landscape format */
        percentOther:       100,            /* Scale portrait and square format */
        preloadImages:      false,           /* Toggles loading bar (false: requires img attributes height and width) */
        reflections:        false,           /* Toggle reflections */
        reflectionGET:      '',             /* Pass variables via the GET method to the reflect_.php script */
        reflectionP:        0.5,            /* Height of the reflection in percent of the source image */
        reflectionPNG:      false,          /* Toggle reflect2.php or reflect3.php */
        reflectPath:        '',             /* Path to the reflect_.php script */
        scrollbarP:         0.6,            /* Width of the scrollbar in percent */
        slider:             false,           /* Toggle slider */
        sliderCursor:       'e-resize',     /* Slider cursor type - default is 'default' */
        sliderWidth:        17,             /* Width of the slider in px */
        slideshow:          false,          /* Toggle slideshow */

        xStep:              180             /* Step width on the x-axis in px */
    };
```

what is this called????

Comment: this is not the same question , m asking  where i can read about that so i can edit by myself

Answer (score 0):

These are the default values that are initialized on the load of this js file unless we didnt re initialized them externally....If we call this js file then the default values will be used for the loading functions,and if we call this js with the custome values then those values will be replaced by the new values and they will be processed furthurly,

You can change these values also,but make sure that you need to follow the data types,and boolean values etc.